# how to set up monit to monitor disk-space

Tags: debian, monitoring, disk-space-utilization, monit

I use monit on my server to monitor apache and mysql running.

Now I want to add an alert if the disk gets too full. I added this for testing in `/etc/monit/monitrc`:

```
check device rootfs with path /dev/md0
    if space usage > 10% then alert
```

I have two partitions I want to check: `/` and `/var`:

```
mount
/dev/md0 on / type ext3 (rw)
/dev/md2 on /var type ext3 (rw)
```

What are useful checks in this configuration apart from diskspace?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There isn't much to do here. Your current check is syntactically correct, but may not be practical. Why do you care if space utilization is greater than 10%??!?

A typical disk check stanza would look like:

```
check device var with path /var
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert
```

That basically will send an email if the drive is more than 80% full. Monit will also let you know once the data usage falls below that level. Also look at the [Monit documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#FILESYSTEM-FLAGS-TESTING).

Type `monit status` at the command line. Here's what Monit sees about your filesytem:

```
Filesystem 'var'
  status                            Accessible
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  permission                        755
  uid                               0
  gid                               0
  filesystem flags                  0x400
  block size                        4096 B
  blocks total                      1523090 [5949.6 MB]
  blocks free for non superuser     979860 [3827.6 MB] [64.3%]
  blocks free total                 1058477 [4134.7 MB] [69.5%]
  inodes total                      1572864
  inodes free                       1563392 [99.4%]
  data collected                    Sat, 03 Aug 2013 22:07:28
```

Comment: 10% was only for testing

Comment: what about the other examples in the config file? `
#    if inode usage > 80% then alert

` Is it important to check inodes extra?

Comment: Not unless you're planning a lot of files on the filesytem...

Comment: I think `check device` must be some old syntax, because the manual doesn't mention it anymore. I think `check filesystem` is the new way to do it.

Comment: @RyanTM is right. Check the new syntax here https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html